# Running batch file as a thread not a process

Tags: java, batch-file, process, resources

am trapped in a situation where I need to say ... infinitely , create a process i.e a batch file which converts a given file.pdf to file.txt the problem am facing is ,,, in order to do this on all the files , the program is creating a process to run the batch file , waits for it to finish , create another process ... and so on , which is consuming resources how can I save my resources ?

```
String[] arg = { "cmd", "/C", "bat.exe", "-layout", arg0,
            arg1};
    try {


        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(arg);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p2 = builder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p2.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        p2.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where arg0 and arg1 are my pdf file and destination text file respectively

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/) does this for free. Have a look at the section *Unblock Your Execution* in the [tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html).

Comment: what i want to do is ... create only one process , to which i pass arguments during runtime